# Why does `convert=ghostscript` destroy equations on high density?

Tags: standalone, conversion, png, ghostscript

I want to create a high-resolution png to include it into a A0-poster. My Idea was to use the `standalone` package with the `convert=ghostscript` option.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,convert={ghostscript, density={4000}}, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        \partial_tx(z,t) &=
        \Lambda(z)\partial_z^2x(z,t) + \Phi(z)\partial_zx(z,t) + A(z)x(z,t)
        \label{pdes}\\
        \partial_zx(0,t) &= Q_0x(0,t),\\
        \partial_zx(1,t) &= Q_1x(1,t) + u(t),    
        \end{align}
\end{document}
```

And here is the result:
[image: strange equation]

I have installed ghostscript version 9.27 and tried both 32 and 64 bit version, both with the same result.
Interestingly, the result depends on the density, it works fine until about 3500. For 10000, the symbols are no more flipped but there are huge white spaces between the symbols. What's the matter with that and how can I avoid this?

Comment: What software is the poster being made in? Doesn't it support vector graphics? Output of pdflatex is vector graphics, so is output of latex + dvips (-E).

Comment: Works fine with Ghostscript 9.26 and TeXLive 2019. Note that we have heard of several bug in ghostscript 9.27 so you might be getting hit by one of those.

Comment: @daleif I want to include the picture in PowerPoint. Tried eps but powerpoint can't show the image. Is there a better way than a high-res bitmap?

Comment: PoiwerPoint should be able to handle EPS. Why not just do he entire poster in LaTeX to begin with.

Comment: I would probably, but its a collaboration, so not in my hand. Think I won't come around using some additional software like inkscape...

Answer (score 1):

Generated PDF with normal `pdflatex`, then opened in Inkscape and saved as PNG with 4000dpi reslution: (see a small details, it's a monster PNG):

[image]